# LEGO 42095 wheels going opposite directions

Tags: technic

My son just finished [the 42095 Remote-Controlled Stunt Racer](https://brickset.com/sets/42095-1) and the two wheels go in opposite directions. Have checked and rebuilt and still can’t get it running in the same direction. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 15):

I believe you forgot a critical step in the instructions, namely step 84:

[image]

It shows how to position the black switches on the remote control, they reverse directions.

Comment: It is so critical that they have even left the two circles showing it on step 85.